# How can I wrap react-draft-wysiwyg editor with some tag (without including toolbar)?

Tags: react-draft-wysiwyg

I have a simple react-draft-wysiwyg editor, and I want to add some extra tags around the editor window (without including toolbar),for example label. Is there any possible way to do that?

[image]